# Connected Component Labeling via Code c++

Tags: c++, image, components, labeling

I have stored a Binary histogram of an image. I am trying to label the different connected components with different levels of gray. Ie there will be no level 255 left.

I think I have some working code, the problem is that it is taking too long to run. I am wondering if there is a faster way, or if there is a problem.

```
//first pass

int label = 256;
vector<int> states; 
int cur, top, left;
for(size_t y = 0; y < original_image.rows; y++){
  for(size_t x = 0; x < original_image.cols; x++){
    cur = hist3[y*modified_image.cols + x];
    if(cur == 255){
      top = hist3[(y-1)* modified_image.cols + x];  

      left = hist3[y*modified_image.cols + x - 1];

      if(left > 255 && top <= 255){
        cur = left;
      } else if(top > 255 && left <= 255){
        cur = top;
      } else if(top > 255 && left > 255){
        if(top < left){
          cur = top;
          states.push_back(top);
          states.push_back(left);
        } else if(left < top){
          cur = left;
          states.push_back(left);
          states.push_back(top);
        }
      } else {
        cur = label;
      }
      hist3[y*modified_image.cols + x] = cur;
    } else{
      label++;
    }
  }
}
```

now in states, i have stored the areas where a compromise had to be made between top and left, stored as 1,2,3,4 where all 2's need to be 1's and all 4'3.

Here is the really slow part. I think it works, but I am going through that list of states that I made starting with the highest value. I then go through it converting down the highest value to the lowest values.

```
vector<int> tops;
for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++){
  tops.push_back(states[i+1]);
}

sort (tops.begin(), tops.begin()+4); 

for(int i = tops.size() -1; i > 0; i--){
  for(int j = states.size() -1; j > 0; j -= 2){
      if(tops[i] == states[j]){
        for(int p = 0; p < hist3.size(); p++){
          if(hist3[p] == states[j]){
            hist3[p] = states[j-1];
          }
        }
      }
   } 
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I see that. I am wondering how to fix it.

Comment: First, make sure you are running an optimized version of your program.  If you're running a "debug" or unoptimized version, then rebuild your application with optimizations turned on and retest.